# How can I get a List of the code that the player is typing in the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I tried but the text is never show on the text mesh :

SecurityKeypadKeys script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadKeys : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would rather go this way round
    // Configure the number for each key via the Inspector
    // they will then set their own names for debugging
    // I wouldn't the other way round rely on that the names are correct
    [SerializeField] private int _number;

    // Here you can attach callback handlers that will be executed
    // For each time this key is pressed
    public event Action<int> onKeyPressed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        name = $"Key {_number}";
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // This class is only responsible for invoking its event
        // It doesn't know and has no authority over how many digits are allowed in the display etc
        // it doesn't even know a display exists or that the values get stored by someone
        onKeyPressed?.Invoke(_number);
    }
}
```

The SecurityKeypadSystem script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // rather let this class control the display text
    [SerializeField] private TextMesh _text;

    [Header("Settings")]
    // also rather let this class control the length of a code
    [SerializeField] private int _codeLength = 8;

    [Header("Debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _keyPadNumbers;
    [SerializeField] private List<int> _code = new List<int>();

    // This will be invoked once the code length has reached the target length
    public event Action<int> OnCodeComplete;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        _keyPadNumbers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Keypad");

        // register a callback to each key that handles the numbers
        foreach (var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            // It is save to remove an event even if it hasn't been added yet
            // this makes sure it is only added exactly once
            // only adding this here for the case you later have to move this again to Update for some reason ;)
            var securityKeypadKeys = keyPadNumber.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed += HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // just for completeness you should always remove callbacks as soon as they are not needed anymore
        // in order to avoid any exceptions
        foreach (var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            var securityKeypadKeys = keyPadNumber.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    // this is called when a keypad key was pressed
    private void HandleKeyPressed(int value)
    {
        // add the value to the list
        _code.Add(value);

        _text.text += value.ToString();

        // Check if the code has reached the target length
        // if not do nothing
        if (_code.Count < _codeLength) return;

        // if it reached the length combine all numbers into one int
        var exponent = _code.Count;
        float finalCode = 0;
        foreach (var digit in _code)
        {
            finalCode =digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
            exponent--;
        }

        // invoke the callback event
        OnCodeComplete?.Invoke((int)finalCode);

        // and reset the code
        ResetCode();
    }

    // Maybe you later want an option to clear the code field from the outside as well
    public void ResetCode()
    {
        _code.Clear();
        _text.text = "";
    }

    // also clear the input if this gets disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ResetCode();
    }
}
```

Last the UnlockCrate script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class UnlockCrate : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private int _targetCode;

    public GameObject securityKeyPad;
    public GameObject player;
    public Animation anim;
    public IKControl ikControl;
    public InteractableItem interactableItem;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCam;
    public CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCam;
    public CamerasControl camerasContorl;

    private bool playAnimOnce = false;

    [SerializeField] private SecurityKeypadSystem securityKeypadSystem;

    private void Start()
    {
        // as before attach a handler that is triggered once the system completes one code
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete -= HandleInputCode;
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete += HandleInputCode;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete -= HandleInputCode;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= interactableItem.distance)
        {
            if (!playAnimOnce)
            {
                if (ikControl.handFinishedMove == true)
                {
                    securityKeyPad.SetActive(true);
                    virtualCam.enabled = true;
                    freeLookCam.enabled = false;
                    Cursor.visible = true;
                    camerasContorl.enabled = false;

                    /*if(securityKeyPad.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>().UnlockedCode() == true)
                    {
                        securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
                        virtualCam.enabled = false;
                        freeLookCam.enabled = true;
                        Cursor.visible = false;
                        anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                    }*/


                    //anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                    playAnimOnce = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (playAnimOnce)
        {
            securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
            virtualCam.enabled = false;
            freeLookCam.enabled = true;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            camerasContorl.enabled = true;
            anim.Play("Crate_Close");
            playAnimOnce = false;
        }
    }

    private void HandleInputCode(int inputCode)
    {
        if (inputCode == _targetCode)
        {
            Debug.Log("Code correct!", this);
            anim.Play("Crate_Open");
            // TODO whatelse has to be done
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"WRONG CODE: Expected {_targetCode} but was {inputCode}!", this);
            // TODO some wrong code animation?
        }
    }
}
```

This screenshot is showing the Security Keypad System GameObject with the script attached to it :

The game start when the Security Keypad (1) is enabled false not active :

[Security Keypad System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qZ5y.jpg)

If I enable true just to show how it looks like the Security Keypad (1) gameobject then each Key cube is like a button with the OnMouseDown event and each cube have attached the script SecurityKeypadKeys :

[Security Keypad (1) enabled true just to show how it looks like in the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKlGi.jpg)

The Security Keypad GameObject is the small keypad system on the left in the scene view and when the player is getting closer to it then the Security Keypad (1) the bigger one is getting active.

On the bottom the gameobject Security Keypad Text is the Text Mesh that should show the numbers pressed.

On the GameObject Crate_0_0 is attached the script UnlockCrate and as target code for testing I added 12345678

The problem now is that it's never getting to the HandleKeyPressed method in the SecurityKeypadSystem script. I used a break point and it's never get there.

I also checked with a break point on the SecurityKeypadKeys script and it's getting the pressed number name but it's never get to the HandleKeyPressed method.

Comment: the code has always the same length? if not how do you know its the end of code??

Comment: why are you doing this in `Update` at all? You should rather make it event driven and only update your list and trigger further behavior for each time a number is added ... not poll-checking things each frame ;) Also what are you using multiple keypad instances for if then you anyway fill the same information to all of them? what is `Number(number);` supposed to do? And in particular what is `int number = go.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>().Number();` supposed to return? This method doesn't exist since it expects an argument ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned there are some uncleared things but most importantly: I would make the entire system more event driven and not poll-check stuff in `Update` every frame.

I would also separate the responsibilities for each component as clear as possible. E.g. like

- `SecurityKeypadKeys` is only responsible for handling it's own key press. It doesn't know/care what happens with this keypress. It doesn't even know who will handle it or that something like a code or display text exist.
- `SecurityKeypadSystem` this is responsible for handling key presses, store the so far input code, control the display, combine the digits and fire an event once a code is complete. It has no further knowledge about what will happen with this code. It doesn't even know who will handle it
- `UnlockCrate` is in your setup the most "powerful" class. It enables/disables the entire `SecurityKeypadSystem`, handles the code once it is complete, validates it and finally is responsible for opening the box .. or not. It doesn't have to know that something like a display text exists - it only cares about the final code.

So it could look somewhat like e.g.

```
public class SecurityKeypadKeys : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would rather go this way round
    // Configure the number for each key via the Inspector
    // they will then set their own names for debugging
    // I wouldn't the other way round rely on that the names are correct
    [SerializeField] private int _number;

    // Here you can attach callback handlers that will be executed
    // For each time this key is pressed
    public event Action<int> onKeyPressed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        name = $"Key {_number}";
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // This class is only responsible for invoking its event
        // It doesn't know and has no authority over how many digits are allowed in the display etc
        // it doesn't even know a display exists or that the values get stored by someone
        onKeyPressed?.Invoke(_number);
    }
}
```

Then one step up in the System you register a callback handler to these keys so every time a key is pressed you update your text field and store the values:

```
public class SecurityKeypadSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // rather let this class control the display text
    [SerializeField] private TextMesh _text;

    [Header("Settings")]
    // also rather let this class control the length of a code
    [SerializeField] private int _codeLength = 8;

    [Header("Debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _keyPadNumbers;
    [SerializeField] private List<int> _code = new List<int>();

    // This will be invoked once the code length has reached the target length
    public event Action<int> OnCodeComplete;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        _keyPadNumbers = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SecurityKeypadKeys>();

        // register a callback to each key that handles the numbers
        foreach(var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            // It is save to remove an event even if it hasn't been added yet
            // this makes sure it is only added exactly once
            // only adding this here for the case you later have to move this again to Update for some reason ;)
            keyPadNumber.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
            keyPadNumber.onKeyPressed += HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // just for completeness you should always remove callbacks as soon as they are not needed anymore
        // in order to avoid any exceptions
        foreach(var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            keyPadNumber.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    // this is called when a keypad key was pressed
    private void HandleKeyPressed(int value)
    {
        // add the value to the list
        _code.Add(value);

        _text.text += value.ToString();

        // Check if the code has reached the target length
        // if not do nothing
        if(_code.Count < _codeLength) return;

        // if it reached the length combine all numbers into one int
        var exponent = code.Count;
        var finalCode = 0;
        foreach(var digit in _code)
        {
            finalCode = digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
            exponent--;
        }
    
        // invoke the callback event
        OnCodeComplete?.Invoke(finalCode);

        // and reset the code
        ResetCode();
    }

    // Maybe you later want an option to clear the code field from the outside as well
    public void ResetCode()
    {
        _code.Clear();
        _text.text = "";
    }

    // also clear the input if this gets disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ResetCode();
    }
}
```

So finally again from the last class you would add another callback handler which validates the User input and triggers your unlocking

```
public class UnlockCrate : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerilaizeField] private int _targetCode;

    public GameObject player;
    public Animation anim;
    public IKControl ikControl;
    public InteractableItem interactableItem;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCam;
    public CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCam;
    public CamerasControl camerasContorl;

    private bool playAnimOnce = false;

    [SerializeField] private SecurityKeypadSystem securityKeypadSystem;

    private void Start()
    {
        // as before attach a handler that is triggered once the system completes one code
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete -= HandleInputCode;
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete += HandleInputCode;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete -= HandleInputCode;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);
        
        if (distance <= interactableItem.distance)
        {
            if (!playAnimOnce)
            {
                if(ikControl.handFinishedMove == true)
                {
                    securityKeyPad.SetActive(true);
                    virtualCam.enabled = true;
                    freeLookCam.enabled = false;
                    Cursor.visible = true;
                    camerasContorl.enabled = false;

                    /*if(securityKeyPad.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>().UnlockedCode() == true)
                    {
                        securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
                        virtualCam.enabled = false;
                        freeLookCam.enabled = true;
                        Cursor.visible = false;
                        anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                    }*/


                    //anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                    playAnimOnce = true;
                }               
            }
        }
        else if (playAnimOnce)
        {
            securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
            virtualCam.enabled = false;
            freeLookCam.enabled = true;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            camerasContorl.enabled = true;
            anim.Play("Crate_Close");
            playAnimOnce = false;
        }
    }

    private void HandleInputCode(int inputCode)
    { 
        if(inputCode == _targetCode)
        {
            Debug.Log("Code correct!", this);
            anim.Play("Crate_Open");
            // TODO whatelse has to be done
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"WRONG CODE: Expected {_targetCode} but was {inputCode}!", this);
            // TODO some wrong code animation?
        }
    }
}
```

---

Of course I don't know your entire project so this is just a general idea - I hope I made it clear for you to understand the concept :)